# How does character death/resurrection work in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, character-death, curse-of-strahd, resurrection

While I was asking some questions in general chat about death in the *Curse of Strahd* adventure, @Derpy brought up an interesting point (that might contain loose spoilers).

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the rulebook/guide itself makes it clear that

> even souls are trapped in the realm. If you die there, your soul can't reach the afterlife. I think there is even a 24 hours rule somewhere in the book: resurrection after 24 hours = free madness points for realizing you cannot even really die.

Is this true, and if so, where in the campaign guide does it say so?

Answer (score 10):

## You are correct about how death works in *Curse of Strahd*.

It is described in [this subheading](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/the-lands-of-barovia#ResurrectionMadness) under "Alterations to Magic" on p. 24 of the adventure:

> ***Resurrection Madness***
>
>  In Barovia, the souls of the dead are as trapped as the souls of the living. They become caught in the mists and can’t travel to the afterlife.
>
>  When a humanoid who has been dead for at least 24 hours returns to life, either by way of a spell or some supernatural means, it gains a random form of indefinite madness brought on by the realization that its spirit is trapped in Barovia, likely forever. To determine how this madness is expressed, roll on the [Indefinite Madness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#IndefiniteMadness) table in chapter 8 of the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*.

Answer (score 6):

Correct; the reference can be found on page 24 of the Curse of Strahd book.